# Ember.js: How can I reuse controllers / views of another route

Tags: ember.js

I have complete contact edit dialog. I now would like to create the matching new contact dialog with the least necessary effort. The new dialog is identical, appart from the model initialisation.

I have the following New route:

```
App.ContactNewRoute = App.BaseEntityRoute.extend({
        init: function () {
            this._super();
            this.keyName = "contact_id";
            this.controllerRoute = "contact.new";
            this.datasource = App.contactDataSource.getNewContact;
        }
});
```

How can I tell ember that it should use the ContactEditController and ContactEditView for this route?

Comment: Do you wanna reuse the Controller class or also the exact same instance? I see a possible solution for each case.

Comment: I want to reuse the controller class..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reuse the class, why not try something like this?

```
App.ContactNewController = App.ContactEditController.extend();

App.ContactNewView = App.ContactEditView.extend();
```

Ember now finds the classes based on its naming schema and everything should be fine.  But why do you actually need that? You are basically mirroring all parts of an route in a new route with a new name, but all other components (controller, view) stay the same?

Comment: so what you are saying, is that it would be better to transition to the ContactEdit route with a fake id? e.g. contact.edit.0

Comment: Oh, i just did notice that i haven't thought about your usecase thorougly.^^ You want to back the usecase of creating a new contact and editing a contact backed by the same controller. So, i guess this approach is fine then. The only other way would be to do a combined component, where you can edit and create. But then i would not be easy to jump into the create state by providing an url.

Comment: In this case you could have to use as fake id, as you mentioned above. So my proposal is fine for this case, as it seems like an emberish appraoch to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ember mixin can also be used for this:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: Yeah, this is also a interesting approach! But i would prefer to create a mixin for more general logic, which is reused more than one time. But this is just my gut feeling.